# C - Counting the occurrence of same number in an array

Tags: c, arrays, count

I have an array in C where:

```
int buf[4];
buf[0] = 1;
buf[1] = 2;
buf[2] = 5;
buf[3] = 2;
```

and I want to count how many elements in the array that have the same value with a counter.
In the above example, the number of elements of similar value is `2` since there are two `2`s in the array.

**I tried:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int buf[4];
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    buf[0] = 1;
    buf[1] = 2;
    buf[2] = 5;
    buf[3] = 2;
    int length = sizeof(buf) / sizeof(int); 

    for (i=0; i < length; i++) {
        if (buf[i] == buf[i+1]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("count = %d", count);
    return 0;
 }
```

but I'm getting `0` as the output. Would appreciate some help on this.

---

## Update

Apologies for not being clear.

**First:**
the array is limited to only of size `4` since it involves `4` directions, left, bottom, top and right.

**Second:**
if there is at least `2` elements in the array that have the same value, the `count` is accepted. Anything less will simply not register.

**Example:**

```
1,2,5,2 
count = 2 since there are two '2's in the array.

1,2,2,2
count = 3 since there are three '2's in the array

1,2,3,4
count = 0 since there are no similarities in the array. Hence this is not accepted.
```

Anything less than the `count = 2` is invalid.

Comment: first off, i'd recommend doing `i < length - 1` instead of `i < length`.  using `i + 1` when `i` is `length - 1` for an array index is UB

Comment: Run through what that does on paper. If [0] == [1] add 1 to the count. If [1] == [2] add 1 to the count. If [2] == [3] ...See what you're missing? You also run off the end of the array on your last time through the loop.

Comment: Whenever you need the "frequency" of occurrence for multiple values, use a "frequency array" with `max - min` elements (initialized all zero). Then simply loop over each element in `buf` incrementing the corresponding index of your frequency array, e.g. It will require a pass to determine the max and min, then either allocate or use a VLA. E.g. `5-1` requires 4 elements. `int freq[max-min];` With a VLA `memset (freq, 0, (max-min) * sizeof *freq);` Then `for (int i = 0; i < max-min; i++) freq[buf[i]-min]++;` Finally `for (int i = 0; i < max-min; i++) printf ("%d: %d\n", i+min, freq[i]);`

Comment: What is the expected value if the array size is 6 and the elements are `1,2,5,2,5,5`? Should it count no of 2's or no of 5's or sum of 2's + sum of 5's?

Comment: @RishikeshRaje i've only limited the array up to the size of 4 since it involves getting values from four adjacent direction, top, left, bottom and right. in that case, if i have 1,2,5,2 and the count is 2, i accept the count value if it's >= 2.

Comment: @David C.Rankin sorry i wasn't being specific earlier on. Please see the updated post.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I normally suggest frequency array(or hashmap) myself too. But if there will be only 4 elements in array, frequency array will be one of the worst possible approaches because of memory usage(assuming data type of `buf` is `int`, he will need an array with `sizeof(int)` elements).

Comment: Yes, they are super handy, and for small problems, the overhead isn't much more than several nested loops that would be used anyway. However, I do agree in the case of 4-elements, where all you care about is whether 2 match, then a procedural count will work fine as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really rather hamstrung by the order the values appear within `buf`. The only rudimentary way to handle this when limited to 4-values is to make a pass with nested loops to determine what the matching value is, and then make a single pass over `buf` again counting how many times it occurs (and since you limit to 4-values, even with a pair of matches, your `count` is limited to `2` -- so it doesn't make a difference which you count)

A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int buf[] = {1, 2, 5, 2},
        length = sizeof(buf) / sizeof(int), 
        count = 0,
        same = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)    /* identify what value matches */
        for (int j = i + 1; i < length; i++)
            if (buf[i] == buf[j]) {
                same = buf[i];
                goto saved;     /* jump out of both loops when same found */
            }
    saved:;    /* the lowly, but very useful 'goto' saves the day - again */

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)    /* count matching numbers */
        if (buf[i] == same)
            count++;

    printf ("count = %d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arr_freq_count
count = 2
```

While making that many passes over the values, it takes little more to use an actual *frequency* array to fully determine how often each value occurs, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (void) {

    int buf[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 6},
        n = sizeof buf / sizeof *buf,
        max = INT_MIN,
        min = INT_MAX;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* find max/min for range */
        if (buf[i] > max)
            max = buf[i];
        if (buf[i] < min)
            min = buf[i];
    }

    int range = max - min + 1;      /* max-min elements (inclusive) */
    int freq[range];                /* declare VLA */

    memset (freq, 0, range * sizeof *freq); /* initialize VLA zero */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)     /* loop over buf setting count in freq */
        freq[buf[i]-min]++;

    for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) /* output frequence of values */
        printf ("%d occurs %d times\n", i + min, freq[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** add a sanity check on the range to prevent being surprised by the amount of storage required if `min` is actually close to `INT_MIN` and your `max` is close to `INT_MAX` -- things could come to quick stop depending on the amount of memory available)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/freq_arr
1 occurs 1 times
2 occurs 2 times
3 occurs 1 times
4 occurs 1 times
5 occurs 2 times
6 occurs 1 times
```

After your edit and explanation that you are limited to 4-values, the compiler should optimize first rudimentary approach just fine. However, for any more than 4-values or when needing the frequency of anything (characters in a file, duplicates in an array, etc..), think *frequency* array.

Comment: C.Rankin in your first example, if i were to have an array of 2,2,5,2 i get the count = 1 which should be 3.

Comment: @Maxxx - yes sorry, replace the `break` by a `goto` to jump out of both loops. A `break;` only exits the current loop and since the loops are nested, `same` is reset to `5` in that case. Anytime you need to break more than 1 loop a simple `goto` is needed. Above, I just `goto saved;` and if you notice the *label* for `saved` is outside both loops -- now it will do what you want with all possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that's wrong is that you are only comparing adjacent values in the buf array.  You have to compare all the values to each other.

How to do this is an architectural question.  The approach suggested by David Rankin in the comments is one, using an array of structs with the value and count count is a second, and using a hash table is a third option.  You've got some coding to do!  Good luck.  Ask for more help as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing values of `buf[i]`  and `buf[i+1]`. i.e. You are comparing `buf[0]` with  `buf[1]`, `buf[1]` with `buf[2]` etc.

What you need is a nested for loop to compare all `buf` values with each other.

```
count = 0;
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    for (j=i+1; j<4; j++)
    {
        if (buf[i]==buf[j])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

As pointed out by Jonathan Leffler, there is an issue in the above algorithm in case the input has elements `{1,1,1,1}`. It gives a value of 6 when expected value is 4.

I am keeping it up, as the OP has mentioned that he wants to only check anything above 2. So, this method may still be useful.

Comment: Suppose the array is defined as `int buf[4] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };` — what count will your code give, and what should it give?  I believe the answers are "your code counts 6" and "the answer should be 4" respectively, so your algorithm is a little naïve.